# Mark someone else's answer that sort-of answered your question vs your own answer that really answers the question?

Tags: discussion

[I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41877287/679285). [Someone answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41881140/679285) but it wasn't really a concise answer, it just said a bunch of things, one of which helped me find the answer I was looking for. I then [answered my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891216/679285) which in my opinion is the easiest and correct answer to the question and I have given credit to the guy who helped me get the answer.

At the moment I upvoted the other person who helped me find the answer to my question. Without him I wouldn't have figured it out myself.

I would also like to mark him as the answer to my question just to give him rep for it but at the same time I feel that my answer is really the most concise way to answer my question and would help future folk stumbling onto my question more, even though I get nothing by doing it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

> What should I do?

You should mark as accepted the answer that most helped you. That's the only criteria.

Or choose to not mark **any** answer - that's also entirely valid.

---

If you really feel like giving this person some rep - vote their answer up. Done.